# Getting all possible combinations of an array of objects

Tags: java, algorithm, pseudocode

I have come to a sudden stop in the development of an application of mine.

I need to get all possible combinations of an array of Arguments, for instance the array could look like this

[Integer, Boolean, String]

The total possible combinations would then be 7 (2^X - 1, where X is the amount of arguments, a formula which me and a friend came up with while trying to tackle this problem)

Here's a visualization of the possible combinations.

[Integer, Boolean, String],

[Integer, Boolean],

[Integer, String],

[Integer],

[Boolean, String],

[Boolean] and

[String]

As you can see in the visualization the only thing which is necessary is that the entries always have the same order relative to each other (Integer must always be before Boolean and String, and Boolean must always be before String)

What I am asking is :

**How can I find every possible combination of an array of Strings where the combinations are not limited to any specific length of the present entries but only limited to having the same order of the entries relative to each other?**

If anyone could give me a push in the right direction it would be much appreciated. I have been looking at a few posts about finding every possible value but I could not find any post which was of any help to me.

**If any further information about the problem is needed feel free to ask**

Comment: For an array of size n, enumerate all integers from 0 to 2^n-1.  For the k'th integer in this iteration, output array[i] if and only if the i'th bit of k is 1.  In C, this condition is checked by: if ((k>>i)&1) { printf("%s ", array[i]); }.  Now you convert that to Java.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question-and-answer site, not a code writing service.  Please narrow your question down to something specific and about programming.

Comment: I did not ask for you to write the code, I wanted a push in the right direction @JoeC

Comment: @Jockie I think Ilya's answer is pointing you in the right direction. :-)

Comment: The problem with saying "I want a push in the right direction" is that we have no idea what you've tried or where you're stuck.  The more specific your question, the better the answer you'll get.

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This usually suggests that what you need is half an hour with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.  In this case, you haven't performed your due diligence in researching the question before posting: all possible subsets is covered quite well on the Internet.

Comment: there is a well known algorithm for generating permutations in a natural order: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Generation_in_lexicographic_order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me give you hint:

Check binary presentation of decimal numbers:

```
0 000
1 001
2 010
3 011
4 100
5 101
6 110
7 111
```

Now, lets arrange your combinations in this fashion:

```
[_, _, _]
[_, _, S]
[_, B, _]
[_, B, S]
[I, _, _]
[I, _, S]
[I, B, _]
[I, B, S]
```

Next step is for you to implement N-bit number

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
String[] array = {"Integer","Boolean","String"};
for (int i = 1, max = 1 << array.length; i < max; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0, k = 1; j < array.length; ++j, k <<= 1)
        if ((k & i) != 0)
            System.out.print(array[j] + " ");
    System.out.println();
}
```

result

```
Integer 
Boolean 
Integer Boolean 
String 
Integer String 
Boolean String 
Integer Boolean String
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at a combination problem. Wherein you have (1..N) arguments, you would want to have a combination sequence using the input (1..N). Once you retrieved the combination - you could use the values (v1,v2,v3) as indexes into the argumentList array to retrieve the specific object combinations. **Use the following code from geeksforgeeks as reference and you can build on top of it.**

```
    // Java program to print all combination of size r in an array of size n
import java.io.*;

class Permutation {

    /* arr[]  ---> Input Array
    data[] ---> Temporary array to store current combination
    start & end ---> Staring and Ending indexes in arr[]
    index  ---> Current index in data[]
    r ---> Size of a combination to be printed */
    static void combinationUtil(int arr[], int data[], int start,
                                int end, int index, int r)
    {
        // Current combination is ready to be printed, print it
        if (index == r)
        {
            for (int j=0; j<r; j++)
                System.out.print(data[j]+" ");
            System.out.println("");
            return;
        }

        // replace index with all possible elements. The condition
        // "end-i+1 >= r-index" makes sure that including one element
        // at index will make a combination with remaining elements
        // at remaining positions
        for (int i=start; i<=end && end-i+1 >= r-index; i++)
        {
            data[index] = arr[i];
            combinationUtil(arr, data, i+1, end, index+1, r);
        }
    }

    // The main function that prints all combinations of size r
    // in arr[] of size n. This function mainly uses combinationUtil()
    static void printCombination(int arr[], int n, int r)
    {
        // A temporary array to store all combination one by one
        int data[]=new int[r];

        // Print all combination using temprary array 'data[]'
        combinationUtil(arr, data, 0, n-1, 0, r);
    }

    /*Driver function to check for above function*/
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        int r = 3;
        int n = arr.length;
        printCombination(arr, n, r);
    }
}
```

Reference: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-possible-combinations-of-r-elements-in-a-given-array-of-size-n/